# How to include Routes in React without making the webpage blank?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a website by watching tutorial in Udemy.

The instructor added `Route` in one of the file, and I did the same, but my webpage becomes blank after adding it.

I also tried including `Routes` but that didn't help.

Here's my code:

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main classname="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      </Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YdQ7.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using `react-router-dom@6`. The `Routes` component API changed significantly from v5 to v6, it no longer takes a `component`, or `render` or `children` function props, all replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. Note that in RRDv6 that all routes are now *always* exactly matched, so there is also no longer any `exact` prop.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Header />
  <main classname="py-3">
    <Container>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
      </Routes>
    </Container>
  </main>
  </Footer />
</Router>
```